# How can I programmatically "click" this button in java?

Tags: java, html, button, apache-commons

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="test" onclick="$(this).vote('<$>votehash</$>', null, event)"></div>
```

I am currently using the [WebClient in the Gargoylesoftware package](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html) and Apache Commons stuff..

Just completely stumped as there is no tab index or standard HTML button.

Comment: @mre, obviously it's a web page

Comment: There is a difference between java and javascript :(

Comment: WebClient is Java, it basically simulates a web browser (HTML and Javascript). It seems pretty cool :) But I don't know what's being asked really. If you can edit the question to make it clearer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simulate a click, what you need to do is call `getElementById("blah");` which returns a `HtmlElement`, then call `click();` on that. If the element is unique, it should have an id attribute, as you'd normally code in HTML. Otherwise, just traverse the DOM as you would normally to find the element.

Comment: That's what I do for all the other buttons in the program, but this is all the code. It's some CSS class.. :/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Reddit code, this seems to work:

```
var n=<<up/down div button>>;
var evt = jQuery.Event("click");
evt.target=n;
jQuery(n).trigger(evt);
```